# Why does bash use/need so many input redirect symbols?

Tags: bash, redirect

I am curious as to the nature and purpose of using multiple "<" characters to satisfy certain bash redirections.  When is each of the <, <<, <<<, syntax correct/preferred?  And under what conditions?  Shouldn't a single "<" be sufficient for a properly written command, function, or subroutine?  In unix 'everything' is a file.  So why mask this with process-substitution?  Isn't that already just a mask for the natural (grouping) capability of any shell?  Or in some cases just a matter of proper order of execution?

Efficiency and performance always have trade-offs, as do ease of read/write ability or ease of usability.  I'm an old dog trying to learn new tricks.  10 lines of code I understand, to perform the same task as one line of code that I do not understand, is worth the trade-off to me.  In my years of scripting, I have had very few situations require writing to non-volatile storage, unless it was intended to be left there ""permanently.

I have not seen such reference for output.  A single ">" will create/overwrite a file.  A double ">>" will create/append a file.  Is there a ">>>" for output too?  This is a redundant question.  I am only interested in the input redirect.

Comment: Do you have a more concrete example? Things like `>` mean "write to" while `>>` means "append to", they have different meanings.

Comment: Have you tried reading [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html)?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I've been trying to read those docs for over twenty years.

Comment: While I mostly agree that `<<<` is not *needed*, it is extremely convenient.  Similarly, although it is possible to do things like `cat 'contents' > file; cmd < file; rm file`, it is more convenient to do `cmd << EOF\ncontents\nEOF`

Comment: I need a better example William.  UUOC comes to mind (sorry) :).  But really, '(command < file | command)', or "(command < file file file)" has gotten me by for decades.  I still prefer back-ticks to $() syntax because it is easier for me to search for matching marks in my editor/IDE than using eyeballs when debugging too.  Is 'cmd << EOF\ncontents\nEOF' the same as 'cmd < "(EOF\ncontents\nEOF)"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple words, they all have different meanings.

- `<` Redirection of input
- `<<` Here Document
- `<<<` Here String (variant of here document)

### Examples

#### `<` Redirection of input

```
grep foo < a-file.txt
```

This redirects the *contents* of `a-file.txt` to `grep`'s standard input. `grep` searches for occurrences of string 'foo' in file `a-file.txt`.

#### `<<` Here Document

```
grep foo <<EOF
foo
foobar
baz
bar
EOF
```

Notice the `EOF` right after `<<` and in the last line. From `man bash`:

> This type of redirection instructs the shell to read input from the current source until a line containing only delimiter (with no trailing  blanks) is seen.

So effectively, `grep` gets the string enclosed by the two `EOF`s as input.

#### `<<<` Here String (variant of here document)

```
grep foo <<<"foobar"
```

You could see this as a "single line" here document (`<<`). `grep` gets the string "foobar" as input.

> Shouldn't a single "<" be sufficient for a properly written command, function, or subroutine?

So, which variant is the correct one to use *depends* on your use case and is indepent from the command you're using, as your shell (most likely `bash`) will take care of them.

I recommend section *3.6 Redirection* of `bash`'s manual for further reading. The sections concerning `<`, `<<` and `<<<` are `3.6.1`, `3.6.6`, `3.6.7`: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections

Comment: That is the best layman's terms answer I could expect.  Thank you!  And I do appreciate the specific manual references.